# Same shell command on different Linux machines produces different output

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script on two different Linux machines which runs the following command:

```
sed 's/ïí/`/g' $inputfile > $outputfile
```

Which is supposed to take an input text file, and generate an output file with all instances of ïí (ASC139 + ASC161) replaced with a backtick character. The command works perfectly on server1, but does not do anything on server2. What could be the cause and possible fix to this?

Here are some details about each server.

Server1

```
***run cmd 'uname -a'*** 
Linux <servername> 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:37:38 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

***run cmd 'lsb_release -a'***
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
Release:        7.1
Codename:       Maipo
```

Server2

```
***run cmd 'uname -a'*** 
Linux <servername> 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

***run cmd 'lsb_release -a'***
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago
```

Let me know if I missed any important system/hardware details that are needed to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such character as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) 139, since ASCII is 7-bit only.

You are likely running into a character encoding problem: The script is written using encoding A and the data file it processes in encoding B, e.g. ASCII or ISO8859 versus UTF-8.

Check this by looking at the environment variable `LC_CTYPE` or `LC_ALL`. Make sure your script's encoding matches the data encoding. You can inspect the actual byte values used for the non-ASCII characters with

```
od -bc script
od -bc data
```

If they don't use the same byte or byte sequence for ïí, that's the reason it doesn't work.

You might also want to compare the output of

```
locale
```

that both servers produce.